# dropped element not visible

Tags: javascript, html

I have a image that gets dropped,but it is not visible here after when Element is dropped.Message gets displayed but the image is not visible when actually dropped.
Dropped Element is not visible when it is dropped.
I know problem may be with `appendchild`, But I can't figure out why it is not 
working.

**here is my code:**
 CSS

```
.droptarget {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }
    .auto-style1 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Javascript

```
  function startDrag(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'You started to Drag!!';
    }

    function allowDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dropElement = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById('dropElement'));
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Element Dropped!!';
    }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="auto-style1">
                <img id="Drag1" src="../Downloads/Nobi.jpg" style="width:34px" height="45px" draggable="true" ondragstart="startDrag(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" />

            </div>
            <div class="droptarget" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

            </div>
            <p id="demo"> </p>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: oh..thank you.. I will keep it in mind for next Question

Comment: Please, explain your problem  and try to ask a good question. This benefits to you because you'll obtain a great and fast answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u0foqvjo/)

Here is the Reverse Case [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u0foqvjo/1/)

Reverse Case HTML

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" title="drag here" id="myImage" src="http://www.rw-designer.com/res/oism.png" />

</div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Try Using this Code

HTML

```
<h1>Drag and Drop</h1>
<span draggable="true" id="div1"  ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <img title="drag here" id="myImage" src="http://www.rw-designer.com/res/oism.png" />
</span>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function drag(ev)
{
//alert('dragged');
ev.dataTransfer.setData("dk",ev.target.id)
} 
function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();

    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("dk");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: Oh it's just works..but the reverse case is not working here i need image to drop again at original place,  back and forth need to go continuously.

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi I updated the Answer. Dont forget to give a Plus Vote :)

Comment: Thanks all for the Vote. Chilllll